# .json file not included in mainBundle?

Tags: iphone, json, nsbundle

I'm creating an iPhone app that includes `.json` files in the resource, but those files couldn't be accessed using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"json"]
```

It seems that these files aren't included in the built app-package. Is there something i have to configure to include .json files in the package?

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with setting the type of the file to `.txt` and then parsing it as if it were json?

Comment: That's fine, but I want to know why .json files aren't included in the package.

Comment: How do you know it's not in the bundle? Can you post what this returns: `NSLog([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"json"]);` Doesn't hurt to check ;)

Comment: [Session started at 2011-02-10 16:33:13 +0900.] (null)

Comment: I also checked the inside of the built package, and there were no .json files inside (while other resource files were).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do, just checking it has been added in the target (the small tick on the right in the picture). And then check the build details logs to verify it has been effectively copied.

[image: json file added as resource]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Targetting for newer version Xcode]

Adding an updated screenshot for XCode 11 on how to access "File Inspector" using right mouse click and how to turn on "Target Membership" (Bottom right on the screen). I spent far too long trying to work this one out

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you include the .json file in the target. You can check if it is copied to your main bundle by inspecting the Resource Copy phase in the target. If the file is listed there, then it's also included in your bundle.

Comment: Thanks, .json files weren't included here!

Comment: Is it possible to configure .json files being automatically added to Resource Copy phase?