# Xcode fails to build on SwiftUI tutorial: You can't use this version of the application "Landmarks" with this version of macOS

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, apple-m1

While working on the SwiftUI tutorial, https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation, adding
`LandmarkRow(landmark: landmarks[0])`
caused the build to fail with the following modals:

Modal 1: Landmarks quit unexpectedly.

- Reopen -> Clicking on this opens Modal 2 below
- Report...
- Ignore

Modal 2: You can't use this version of the
application "Landmarks" with
this version of macOs.

- OK -> Clicking on this closes the modal
- Software Update -> Clicking on this redirects to Software Update in System Preferences (System details below)

Machine: Macbook Pro 14-inch 2020

OS: Mac OS Monterey 12.6

Xcode: Version 14.0.1

Edit 1: Found an additional error message in the canvas of LandmarkRow.swift:

```
Fatal error: Couldn't find landmarkData.json in main bundle.: file
```

Edit 2: The errors thrown by the macOS modals seem misleading. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: M T, upload your modified code to github so we can quickly know what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi @kakaiikaka, thanks for replying. I resolved it by doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874855/8722990. Is there a way to avoid this altogether? I suspect that I made a mistake by copy & pasting the json file into the project directory which may have led to some linking failures.

Comment: Ah, so common issue for an apple developer. Always check target membership in Xcode's right panel. Be sure to check `Copy items if needed, `Create Groups`, and `Add to targets` when you drag something into the Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Turning on Target Membership for Landmarks within the file landmarkData.json resolved the issue.

How-to: Select landmarkData.json -> Show File Inspector -> Look for 'Target Membership' then tick on 'Landmarks'

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63210190/8722990

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but my issue was I had a typo in the "isFavorite" property name. This caused the

```
return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
```

in the ModelData file to throw the error.

It could not decode the file because the property name did not exist in the JSON file. The property names need to match the JSON keys.

Fixing the typo, fixed the error.